# NETLOGON EventID 5723 for Managed Service Account

Tags: windows, active-directory, netlogon

I'm receiving NETLOGON errors EventID 5723 which states:
"The session setup from computer [AccountName] failed because the security database does not contain a trust account [AccountName] referenced by the specified computer."

The only problem is the account being referenced is NOT a computer account. It's a Managed Service Account. How can this error be thrown for an account that isn't a computer?

Additional Info:

- The account is used as the identity for an AppPool in IIS.
- The account is trusted for delegation.
- It has HTTP SPNs set.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, Group Managed Service accounts are indeed a type of computer account. If you take a look at the objectClass attribute on one of them, you'll see a list of classes including:

- **computer**
- msDS-GroupManagedServiceAccount
- organizationalPerson
- person
- top
- user

Additionally, the sAMAccountType attribute is set to `MACHINE_ACCOUNT` instead of `NORMAL_USER_ACCOUNT`.

Comment: I checked that, the objectClass does list "computer" but the sAMAccountType is NORMAL_USER_ACCOUNT.

Comment: Is it actually a group managed service account that can be referenced by multiple machines? Or is it the old style managed service account that only a single machine can reference?  The gMSAs on my 2012 R2 based domain all have a sAMAccountType of MACHINE_ACCOUNT.

Comment: Their sAMAccountName attributes also all end with a '$' just like computers.

Comment: It's an older MSA. Not a gMSA. The sAMAccountName does end in a '$' though.

Comment: Ah ha. In that case. I'm not sure. My legacy MSAs don't even have computer as an object class. And all of their sAMAccountNames start with a '!' char.